# jQuery insertBefore() not working in single product pages

Tags: jquery

I used insertBefore() to move the product thumbnail before the product image div, but I can't get it to work in my functions.php file.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'swap_product_thumbnail_and_image');
function swap_product_thumbnail_and_image() { ?>

<?php if ( is_product() ) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $(".woocommerce-product-gallery__thumbs-carousel").insertBefore($(".flex-viewport"));
        });
    </script>
<?php }

}
```

This code:

```
$(".woocommerce-product-gallery__thumbs-carousel").insertBefore($(".flex-viewport"));
```

works fine in console chrome devtools

why is it not working when in functions? Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Check the *rendered* HTML to ensure the script is being output correctly.  Check the browser console for any errors, eg incase your script appears before the jquery src=.  Check that the element exists when your (js) code runs, add: `console.log($(".woocommerce-product-gallery__thumbs-carousel").length)` and `console.log($(".flex-viewport").length)` inside the doc.ready - this is the most likely cause if the carousel has not been initiated / not finished initiating when your code runs.

Comment: The code will run when the page is first loaded. Has the thumbnail and image divs been loaded at that time, or are they loaded dynamically later?

Comment: Yes, I got it working now. I forgot to set a timeout. Thanks for the answers! :)